# unable to get the dotnet core preview version listed in dotnet --list-sdks in linux mint os

Tags: .net-core, linux-mint, .net-core-5-preview-2

I am trying to install the dotnet core 5.0 preview 2 version in my linux mint OS.

I did the steps outlined in the below link

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-5.0.100-preview.2-linux-x64-binaries

However, after running all the commands, if i check the new version listing in the SDK's it is not showing.

ex: `dotnet --list-sdks` This shows only the previously installed version 3.1. Also, I have the tar ball extracted in $HOME/dotnet location.

Is there something I am missing, the problem seems to be linux specific, but after following all the given steps, it is really hard to not see the version showing up.

I also edited my .profile file and added the below given 2 lines at the end of the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
```

If any step is missed out or if any logs that i can refer, please let me know